# Between conditions with dates has odd behavior

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-date-functions

I have this T-SQL query in SSMS:

```
DECLARE @TodaysDate datetime
DECLARE @AsAtDate DATETIME

SET @TodaysDate = GETDATE()

PRINT (DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TodaysDate))

IF DATEPART(WEEKDAY, @TodaysDate)  = 2              -- is today Monday?
    SET @AsAtDate = DATEADD(DAY, -3, @TodaysDate)       -- Report contains Friday, Saturday & Sunday
ELSE
    SET @AsAtDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @TodaysDate)       -- Report contains last working day

SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         --app.short_id, 
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), app.created_at, 105) AS [Date Created],
         CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), stat.activity_created, 105) AS [Date Updated],
     FROM
         Table1 app
     LEFT JOIN
         Table2 stat ON app.appID = stat.appID
     WHERE
         stat.activity_created BETWEEN @AsAtDate AND @TodaysDate) T
```

which doesn't seem to return any data.

[image]

but if I change:

```
SET @AsAtDate = DATEADD(DAY, -1, @TodaysDate)
```

to:

```
SET @AsAtDate = DATEADD(DAY, -2, @TodaysDate)
```

it returns some, and the supposed data that should have been returned even if I didn't have to change the code above. For context, today is September 15th, it should have returned 14th.

[image]

Comment: If you run a basic query like SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE activity_created > '14sep2023' I suspect you'll find that the "activity_created" column is "datetime" (and likely you have not only the date value, but also lots of different time values).  So, of course, when you then try and get SQL to compare a value like '14sep2023 8:17:00' to '14sep2023', it assumes that the latter value is '14sep2023 0:00:00', and therefore an actual "datetime" value of '14sep2023 8:17:00' is NOT going to between '13sep2023 0:00:00' and '14sep2023 0:00:00'

Comment: If you really want to just do a date conversion without considering the time of day, then you'd want to do ... WHERE CONVERT(date, stat.activity_created between @AsAtDate and @TodaysDate) ..., and that way the comparison will be strictly '14sep2023' to '14sep2023', without any consideration of the actual hour/minute/second portion of the stored "datetime" value

Comment: This worked, but I still had to change to SET @AsAtDate = DATEADD(DAY,-2, @TodaysDate) for me to get the previous date.

Comment: Change your declaration of those two variables to be Declare @ TodaysDate date   DECLARE @ AsAtDate date   (rather than "datetime" for the variables)    ..... (obviously no space in between the @ and the variable name, but StackOverflow is giving me the weird error about trying to notify multiple users with my @)

Comment: @Craig put them on code blocks e.g. `Declare @TodaysDate date DECLARE @AsAtDate`

Comment: @DaleK - I have no idea how to do that in a comment .....

Comment: @Craig single backticks, same as in a question :) Also a quick google will tell you

Comment: Honestly, when working with date and time data types, you are far better off with `>=` and `< ` logic. Even when working with `date`s I then to use this logic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be helpful in demonstrating the potential issue you're seeing.

There are three `SELECT`s.
The first returns values from a `DATETIME` column where it's between two dates (which are implicitly converted to date times, with the time portion set to `00:00:00.000`).
The second uses a specific time portion in the `WHERE`.
Finally the `DATETIME`s are cast to `DATE` and compared to `DATE`.

```
;WITH DateTimes AS (
SELECT GETDATE() AS DateTime
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(HOUR,1,DateTime)
  FROM DateTimes
 WHERE DateTime < DATEADD(DAY,2,GETDATE())
), Dates AS (
SELECT CAST(DateTime AS DATE) AS Date
  FROM DateTimes
)

SELECT *, '2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16'
  FROM DateTimes
 WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2023-09-15' AND '2023-09-16'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, '2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997'
  FROM DateTimes
 WHERE DateTime BETWEEN '2023-09-15 00:00:00.000' AND '2023-09-16 23:59:59.997'
UNION ALL
SELECT *, '2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16'
  FROM Dates
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '2023-09-15' AND '2023-09-16';
```

You can see the difference in the results.
In the first the `DATETIME`s filtered by a date don't include anything after midnight on the end date, because it's not between the two literals.

When we add the time, we now get the rows expected, all the `DATETIME`s on those two days are returned.

Similarly when we explicitly cast the `DATETIME`s to a `DATE` and filter by date we get all the rows for both dates.

| DateTime | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-09-15 09:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 10:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 11:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 12:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 13:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 14:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 15:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 16:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 17:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 18:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 19:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 20:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 21:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 22:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 23:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 09:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 10:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 11:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 12:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 13:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 14:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 15:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 16:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 17:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 18:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 19:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 20:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 21:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 22:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 23:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 00:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 01:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 02:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 03:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 04:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 05:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 06:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 07:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 08:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 09:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 10:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 11:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 12:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 13:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 14:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 15:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 16:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 17:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 18:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 19:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 20:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 21:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 22:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-16 23:32:45.210 | 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 AND 2023-09-16 23:59:59.997 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-15 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |
| 2023-09-16 00:00:00.000 | 2023-09-15 AND 2023-09-16 |